# how to add an empty list to a tuple

Tags: python

I need to add an empty list to an existing tuple.
example:

```
>>> ([1],[1,2]) + ([])  
([1],[1,2],[])
```

My problem is that python seems to evaluate `([])` to `[]` on which i can't use the `+` operator.

I tried `tuple([])` but that evaluates to `()` and nothing is added to the original tuple.

Thank you.

Comment: of course, tuples are immutable. So you don't actually extend the original tuple.

Comment: `([])` isn't a tuple, it's just `[]` enclosed in expression parentheses.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a one-element tuple:

```
([], )
#  ^
```

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
>>> ([1],[1,2])+([],)
([1], [1, 2], [])
```

Simply putting something in between parentheses makes it an expression. Add a comma at the end to mark it as a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
([1],[1,2]) + ([],)
```

Answer (score 1):

tuples are immutable so you need to make a new tuple

```
a=([1],[1,2])
b=a+([],)
```